# VBA code giving inconsistent results on consistent Data

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have exhausted my knowledge/resources trying to figure this one out. I am comparing 2 columns A & B. If a value in A is contained in B, then my code should remove the value from A only.

A is a complete unique list, and B is a filtered Unique list. Every value in B should be present in A. the final count of values in A is always 2390, and the final count of B is always 2218 in my current data. Doing the math, I'd be expecting 178 remaining rows in column A.

when I run my following code, I get a different final count every time. 253, 242, 249, 246. I can't seem to understand where the issue is coming from for the life of me. Where did I go wrong?

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateFromOneColumnComparingWithAnother()


Worksheets(2).Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim rngCheck As Range
For Each rngCell In Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(2).Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(rngCell) Then
        Do
            Set rngCheck = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngCheck = Worksheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Find("*" & rngCell.Value & "*")
            rngCheck.ClearContents
            Err.Clear: On Error GoTo -1: On Error GoTo 0
        Loop Until rngCheck Is Nothing

    End If
Next rngCell
Set rngCell = Nothing
Set rngCheck = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong. My approach to this problem is usually to write the columns to arrays, loop through the arrays and compare, write the unique values to a new array, then write that array to whatever location you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I'm pretty novice and not too good at arrays, have tried that suggestion in the past but I always seem to screw it up...

Comment: I'll work on something for you. I'll try to explain the best I can when I post it.

Comment: I would also suggest going into the VBA editor and pressing F8 to go through line by line and finding out where or why your code is inconsistent.  This should help identify which line in your code needs fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code writes each value in column A to the array `a()` and each value in column B to the array `b()`. It then loops through each value in `a()`. For each value in `a()`, it loops through each value in `b()`. If the value is found, it sets `flg` to `TRUE` and doesn't write that to our array `c()`. If `flg` remains `FALSE` it writes the value to array `c()`. We then go back through and write the value in `c()` to column C. You can adjust this to output the uniques (`c()`) to any place you choose.

**EDITED:**

```
Option Explicit


Sub test_array()
Dim a() As String, b() As String, c() As String
Dim flg As Boolean
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim rng As Range
i = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Edited to pull the row, not the cell
j = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Edited to pull the row, not the cell
ReDim a(0 To i - 1)
ReDim b(0 To j - 1)
ReDim c(0 To i - 1)

For k = 0 To i - 1
    a(k) = Cells(k + 1, "a")
Next k

For k = 0 To j - 1
    b(k) = Cells(k + 1, "b")
Next k


k = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(a())
    flg = False
    For j = 0 To UBound(b())
        If a(i) = b(j) Then
            flg = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If flg = False Then
        k = k + 1
        c(k - 1) = a(i)
    End If
Next i

For k = LBound(c()) To UBound(c())
    Cells(k + 1, "c") = c(k)
Next k


End Sub
```

Comment: wow, that was WAY more than I was expecting... I can't tell you how much I appreciate that! Wish I could rep you 1 million times!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. This method is MUCH faster as well, although you may not see the performance difference with only 2K-ish lines.

Comment: I am getting a "Type mismatch" on the "ReDim a(0 To i - 1)" lines. Based on the error definition, I can't see anything wrong...

Comment: Try with my edit above. I edited the `i = ...` and `j = ...`.

Comment: That is super quick! You made my life sooo much easier!

Comment: I transferred the macro to my main worksheet (460,000 lines in this case) and I'm getting the overflow error on 
"For k = 0 To i - 1"
 So I am forced to go away from the 
"Dim i, j, k As Integer"
I've tried "Variant" and "Long" but I'm pretty sure that the array is looking for an integer value here... Regardless of what I try I'm getting a "Type mismatch" on line 
     "If a(i) = b(j) Then"
Is there a way to get this on such a large amount of data bypassing the "Integer" value "Dim i, j, k as Integer"?

Comment: Please see my edit. I was sloppy with my variable declaration. This worked for me with the number of rows you said you had. This will not, however, be nearly as fast with 400K+ lines.

Comment: Thanks for that! That did bypass that 'debug' but now I'm stuck with the same error a couple lines down. I've adjusted some of the 'String' declarations to variant (I know will slow it down a bit) to bypass others, but it's now stuck on "If a(i) = b(j) Then".  I'm slowly coming to the realization that with this much data to sift through, it may not happen... I may have to cut up this final spreadsheet I'm working on and run the macro on smaller chunks of the whole...

Comment: Weird, this worked for me still...I actually think a database might be best. I'm not a SQL expert, but I think this query could be written very easily. in psuedo code `Select value from the numbers in column A where not in (select numbers from column B)`. This would be much faster with the amount of data you have.

Comment: that's actually a really good thought... I'm gonna have to try that!